# how to find out font information with mouse click on pdf document in .net(Jquery and C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

How do I retrieve the font and size of a character that is selected in a PDF document by clicking on it? The document is rendered using pdf.js along with the technologies of jQuery and C#.

```
Technologies: JavaScript, jQuery, C#
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In addition - it seems you are misunderstanding the purpose of this site. StackOverflow is not an advanced abstraction of some interface for search engines or humans trying to solve _your problems_. So please show some effort on your own first before asking for help here.